# Export and import from index.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have been working on angular project and came on this very peculiar problem. I have created separate module for layouts,login and dashboard. On login i want a very specific layout so i did this

```
import { LoginLayout } from '../layouts/login-layout/login-layout.component'; // this works
import { LoginLayout } from '../layouts'; // this doesn't work

import { 
 loginRoute,
 resetPasswordRoute
} './'; 

const LOGIN_ROUTES = [loginRoute, resetPasswordRoute];

export const loginRoute: Routes = [
 path: '',
 component: LoginLayoutComponent,
 children:  LOGIN_ROUTES
]
```

and i am exporting login layout from `index.ts` in `layouts` as

```
...
export * from './login/login-layout/login-layout.compenent';
```

I am not able to understand why one works and the other doesn't 
It doesn't even show any errors

Answer (score 0):

When comparing the folder structure of your import that works with the export in the `index.ts` file then there is an extra folder `./login/`. Maybe this is an additional component with different name that you exporting.

```
import { LoginLayout } from '../layouts/login-layout/login-layout.component'; // this works
```

**index.ts**

```
export * from './login/login-layout/login-layout.compenent';
```

*edit*

This is the folder structure I supposed.

```
├──dashboard
├──layouts
│     ├──index.ts
│     └──login
│            └──login-layout
│                    login-layout.component.ts 
└──login
      └──somefile-with-import.ts
```

Comment: I am sorry i am not able to understand your explanation. What i mean is that when i am imported the exported `component` from `index.ts` it doesn't work but also doesn't show any errors however if i import it directly from the comoponent file it works.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand your question. Can you show as I do in which folder the index.ts and the components file are.